# Arrays as attributes in literal Objects

Tags: javascript

It's not so easy for me to explain the problem, but just look at the sample code.

```js
var test = { 
 my_array: [],
 my_var: ''
}


var a = Object.create(test);
var b = Object.create(test);


a.my_array.push('aaa');
b.my_array.push('bbb');

a.my_var = 'this is obj A';
b.my_var = 'this is obj B';


document.write(a.my_array[0]); //output: aaa
document.write('<br>');
document.write(b.my_array[0]); //output: aaa
document.write('<br>');
document.write(a.my_var); //output: this is obj A
document.write('<br>');
document.write(b.my_var); //output: this is obj B
```

How is it possible that the Object **b** has the same array-value as Object **a**?

Answer (score 2):

You've created two objects that **share** a single prototype object. Properties on object prototypes are found during object property lookups; they are not copied to object instances upon creation.

When you assign a value to an object property as in

```
a.my_var = 'this is obj A';
```

then the property becomes a local "own" property of the object, even if it previously was a prototype property. You cannot change a prototype property value by an assignment like that.

Comment: Ok, i understand the problem. But how can i solve it? Is ist possible to create a seperat Object with seperate Arrays from a Class in the literal notation?

Comment: @EvgeniTch you have to initialize properties on the new objects directly. Typically you would do that in a constructor function. Or you could use `Object.assign()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the way you create the objects, the `my_array` property will have the same reference in both objects. I've provided a simple adaptation to achieve the expected result.

```js
var test = function () {
    return { 
   my_array: [],
   my_var: ''
    }
}

var a = Object.create(test());
var b = Object.create(test());

a.my_array.push('aaa');
b.my_array.push('bbb');

a.my_var = 'this is obj A';
b.my_var = 'this is obj B';

document.write(a.my_array[0]); //output: aaa
document.write('<br>');
document.write(b.my_array[0]); //output: aaa
document.write('<br>');
document.write(a.my_var); //output: this is obj A
document.write('<br>');
document.write(b.my_var); //output: this is obj B
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only ever creating one array object, here:

```
my_array: []
```

When you `Object.create` a new object from that, that array isn't going to be duplicated/cloned/reinstantiated. Both instances share the same array object.

Answer (score 0):

To complete answers, this image is fairly explicit :

[image: Objects]

(I just make a `console.log(a, b)`)

EDIT :

A way to avoid this problem (https://jsfiddle.net/dafuaLkj/):

```
var test = function() {
  this.my_array = [];
    this.my_var = ''
} 


var a = new test();
var b = new test();
```

Comment: Well, no, it's not obvious from the pic that `a.__proto__` and `b.__proto__` are the same object.

Comment: Now, with your comment, it is. Thanks @georg

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is a simple cloning. What you want is a **deep cloning**. For deep cloning, we need to use other alternatives. This is because Object.create() here, copies the property reference when the property being assigned is an object or an array.

If you want a deep copy of an object (that is, a recursive copy of all nested properties, walking the prototype chain), you must use another approach. The following is a possible example. ([Source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#Another_way_deep_copy%E2%80%8E))

```js
function clone(objectToBeCloned) {
  // Basis.
  if (!(objectToBeCloned instanceof Object)) {
    return objectToBeCloned;
  }

  var objectClone;
  
  // Filter out special objects.
  var Constructor = objectToBeCloned.constructor;
  switch (Constructor) {
    // Implement other special objects here.
    case RegExp:
      objectClone = new Constructor(objectToBeCloned);
      break;
    case Date:
      objectClone = new Constructor(objectToBeCloned.getTime());
      break;
    default:
      objectClone = new Constructor();
  }
  
  // Clone each property.
  for (var prop in objectToBeCloned) {
    objectClone[prop] = clone(objectToBeCloned[prop]);
  }
  
  return objectClone;
}

var test = { 
 my_array: [],
 my_var: ''
}


var a = clone(test);
var b = clone(test);


a.my_array.push('aaa');
b.my_array.push('bbb');

a.my_var = 'this is obj A';
b.my_var = 'this is obj B';


document.write(a.my_array[0]); //output: aaa
document.write('<br>');
document.write(b.my_array[0]); //output: aaa
document.write('<br>');
document.write(a.my_var); //output: this is obj A
document.write('<br>');
document.write(b.my_var); //output: this is obj B
```

Comment: There's no cloning at all going on in the original question.